# generate association based on list

Tags: associations

a is a list {1,2,3,4}

b is an association <|1->a, 2->b, 3->c, 4->d|>

I am trying to write a single line of code to get b from a

b=<|#->myFunction[#] &|> /@ a

Here is the output:

Association[#1->myFunction[#1]&][1]

Can someone help find out a correct way to do it?

btw, I can do it using for loop, of course, just trying to see if I can use only one line to do it :-)

Comment: Try `b = <|# -> myFunction[#]|> & /@ a`  do not use `()` for function parameters `Mathematica uses` `[]`

Comment: Also try `a = Range[4]; b = 
 CharacterRange["a", 
  "d"]; Association@((#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &) /@ Transpose[{a, b}])`

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan  I did use [#] in my code, just a typo in my original post, now just corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Just found a function [`AssociationMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationMap.html)

```
listOfKeys = {key1, key2, ...};

AssociationMap[f, listOfKeys] 
->  <|key1->f[key1], key2->f[key2], ...|>
```

Comment: xs = Range[4];
    Association @@ Map[Rule[#, f[#]] &]@xs

Comment: @tomd just realized you had done it before me :) there is also a function `AssociationThread` that merges what you just did.

Answer (score 2):

```
AssociationThread[# -> FromLetterNumber[#]] &@Range[4]
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do :-)  (Variant: `AssociationMap[FromLetterNumber, a]`).

Comment: @tomd thanks ! yours is more compact.